# Bootstrap collapse/expand multiple targets with different collapse states

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In the bootstrap docs, there is an example of how to toggle single and multiple targets, see https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/?#multiple-targets.

When clicking "Toggle the first element" and then "Toggle both elements", the state of the two elements are mismatched e.g. one collapsed the other not.

How can I achieve that both/multiple elements are collapsed/shown when clicking "Toggle both elements" no matter what state the element had before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after [Dealish Teppes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13426903/dealish-teppes) hint, I came up with this solution.
Note to remove the data-target and add id on the "toggle both" button.

```js
var toggle_all = $('#toggle_all')
toggle_all.on('click', function(event) {
  if (toggle_all.attr("aria-expanded") === 'false') {
    $('.multi-collapse').collapse('show')
    toggle_all.attr('aria-expanded', 'true');
  } else {
    $('.multi-collapse').collapse('hide')
    toggle_all.attr('aria-expanded', 'false');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <title>Bootstrap Card Example</title>
</head>

<body>
  <p>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#multiCollapseExample1" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="multiCollapseExample1">Toggle first element</a>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#multiCollapseExample2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="multiCollapseExample2">Toggle second element</button>
    <button id="toggle_all" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="multiCollapseExample1 multiCollapseExample2">Toggle both elements</button>
  </p>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="collapse multi-collapse" id="multiCollapseExample1">
        <div class="card card-body">
          Some placeholder content for the first collapse component of this multi-collapse example. This panel is hidden by default but revealed when the user activates the relevant trigger.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="collapse multi-collapse" id="multiCollapseExample2">
        <div class="card card-body">
          Some placeholder content for the second collapse component of this multi-collapse example. This panel is hidden by default but revealed when the user activates the relevant trigger.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```